# onclick: do something after changing location

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, onclick

Suppose I want to do the following: when clicking a 'div', change to another location (as if it was ...) and then do something. I have tried with this code:

`<div onclick="location.reload();location.href='...';togglebox('#ident')">Title</div>`

where `ident` is the identifier of an object in the new location `href='...'` and `togglebox` is a function defined in the script. But it seems that the browser tries to accomplish `togglebox('#ident')` before changing the location, so the output is not the expected one. For instance, if I try

`<div onclick="location.reload();location.href='...';console.log(5)">Title</div>`

then a `5` appears instantaneously before changing the location, while I expect the browser first changing the location and then showing `5`.

**Is there any solution to this reversal-order solution?**

Any suggestion is welcome

Comment: Once the page has been reloaded, the old javascript will have been unloaded.

Comment: Your JavaScript code is run synchronously, in case you want to do something before the page changes - like prompt the user to make sure they want to change or block/prevent the page change. (Both of these can be very annoying, so only do them with good cause.) But Oriol@'s right, once the page has changed your JS is gone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to use a query string to tell the destination page what to do. However, if you want a hack that will do almost exactly what you ask, you can do this:

*(This goes in your current page's click event handler)*

```
window.location.href = '...'; // Go to another page in your site
localStorage.setItem('exec',"yourCodeInQuotes()");
```

Now the destination page should either be prepared to handle the `ident` you mentioned from `localStorage` or just evaluate the code directly. Either way you need the destination page to anticipate the data that's coming.

*(This goes in the destination page)*

```
var message = localStorage.getItem('exec'); // Will get whatever you stored
eval(message); // Will attempt to run it as JavaScript
$('#'+message); // Or find it if it was your ident and do stuff...
```

Comment: The code looks cool, but I am a bit puzzled because I am a beginner in HTML. How would the entire code be? `<div onclick="window.location.href='...';localStorage.setItem('exec',"yourCodeInQuotes()")">`... and the other piece?

Comment: You should avoid inline event listeners of this size. Instead of using `onclick="..."`, you should go to your javascript file and do `document.querySelector("#your-div").onclick = function(){ /* your code */ }`